# Reuse javascript code across multiple Metro-style apps

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

SOLVED!  See my self-answer below.

---

I'm building two Metro-style apps using Javascript and HTML, which will have different presentation layers but a lot of similar functionality under the hood.  Thanks to the ability to call C# methods from Javascript, I can factor a lot of the "common" functionality into a C# WinMd library that can then be referenced by both top-level apps.

However, there are some utility-type functions that are purely Javascript that I would like to reuse.  There doesn't appear to be a way to create a "WinMD" using Javascript (only C# or C++).

In a .NET world, I would usually just package whatever file as a resource and load it from a common assembly.  Is there a way I could add a "common" .js file to a WinMD as a resource, and access it through some app-aware URL (i.e. ms-appx: or ms-resource: or something like that)?

Comment: If you want a javascript file included in two pages you can use <script source=...> otherwise there are aspects of this question are contradictory:. Can you clarify?

Comment: Well, if you google just the right phrase, you could come up with something on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930.aspx
<br/>>
Hope it helps!

Comment: @ControlAltDel It's not just about including it in two pages; it's about including it in two separate metro apps (i.e. two different projects).  I need the script to live somewhere where it will be accessible by both apps (i.e. packaged with each app).  And just to be clear, hosting the script remotely and retrieving it via http://, etc. is not an option.

Comment: @NikkuAisuru Thanks; that link looks like it applies more to ASP.NET than Metro-style apps, but I will see if I can do anything similar in a Metro-style project and report back...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is as follows:

1. Add the file you wish to reuse to a WinMD class library project (e.g. "MyWinMdProj")
2. Mark the resource as "content" in its property page (usually is by default)
3. Add a reference to the class library from the top-level Metro app
4. Use a script tag with the ms-appx protocol to reference the file, i.e.

< script src="ms-appx:///MyWinMdProj/path/to/file.js" >

Note the three slashes; "MyWinMdProj" is a folder relative the Metro app's package (i.e. ms-appx:///) as opposed to being its own top-level package.

Note that any file included in this manner will be exposed on the filesystem under C:\Program Files\WindowsApps - but all of your html, js, css, etc. files from the top-level app project already are anyway, so you're not any worse off in that regard than if you copied and pasted the code in between two (or more) different apps.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could package your scripts into a Nuget package, similar to how jQuery and Modernizer are done, then just add a Nuget reference to both projects.

http://www.nuget.org